# How can I track and analyze the performance of my eCommerce website?

Tags: e-commerce

What key performance indicators (KPIs) can I track and analyze to assess the performance of my eCommerce website effectively?

To assess the performance of your eCommerce website, there are several key performance indicators (KPIs) you can track and analyze. These KPIs can provide valuable insights into various aspects of your website's performance and help you make data-driven decisions for optimization.